# Solving homogeneous differential equation $y''(x) = ky(x)$ using different approaches leads to different results

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I have the following second order homogeneous linear differential equation:

$$y''(x) = k y\left( x \right), \quad\quad k \in \mathbb{R}$$

---

Using the exponential approach

$$y\left( x \right) = d e^{r x}, \quad \left\{ d,\, r \right\} \in \mathbb{C} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad y'\left( x \right) = d r e^{r x} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad y''\left( x \right) = d r^{2} e^{r x}$$

leads to:

$$
\begin{align*}
y''\left( x \right) &= k y\left( x \right)\\
d r^{2} e^{rx} &= k d e^{r x}\\
r &= \pm \sqrt{k}\\
\Rightarrow y\left( x \right) &= d e^{\sqrt{k} x}\\
\end{align*}
$$

---

Which is a valid solution but now I used a trigonometric approach:

$$
\begin{align*}
y(x) &= a\cos(\omega x) + b\sin(\omega x), \quad \quad \left\{ a,\, b,\, \omega \right\} \in \mathbb{C}\\
y''\left( x \right) &= -a \omega^{2} \cos\left( \omega x \right) - b \omega^{2} \sin\left( \omega x \right) = -\omega^{2} y\left( x \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

Which leads to:

$$
\begin{align*}
y''\left( x \right) &= k y\left( x \right)\\
-\omega^{2} y\left( x \right) &= k y\left( x \right)\\
\omega &= i \sqrt{k}\\
\implies y(x) &= a \cos\left( i \sqrt{k} x \right) + b \sin\left( i \sqrt{k} x \right)
\end{align*}
$$

---

Those seem like different solutions but I know that you should in theory be able to transform one into the other, by using the complex identities for $\cos$ and $\sin$.

$$
\begin{align*}
y\left( x \right) &= a \cos\left( i \sqrt{k} x \right) + b \sin\left( i \sqrt{k} x \right)\\
&= \frac{a}{2} \left( e^{i \left( i \sqrt{k} x \right)} + e^{-i \left( i \sqrt{k} x \right)} \right) + \frac{b}{2 i} \left( e^{i \left( i \sqrt{k} x \right)} - e^{-i \left( i \sqrt{k} x \right)} \right)\\
&= \left( \frac{a}{2} - \frac{b}{2 i} \right) e^{\sqrt{k} x} + \left( \frac{a}{2} + \frac{b}{2 i} \right) e^{-\sqrt{k} x}\\
\end{align*}
$$

But I can't see how these two solutions are equal. Where is the problem?

Comment: But $(\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{2i})e^{-\sqrt{k}x}$ is same as $c_1 e^{-\sqrt{k}x}$  same for the other guy. You can call your constant anything you want.

Comment: I would recommend the MathJax / $\LaTeX$ tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). When reading your $\LaTeX$ code, I noticed that you wrote a lot of things in an unnecessarily complicated way, e.g. you can just write `\qquad` ($a \qquad b$) instead of `\quad\quad` ($a \quad \quad b$) and you hadn't to write it. You can also just write `\implies` ($\implies$) instead of `\Longrightarrow` ($\Longrightarrow$)...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at approach one you seemed to be missing both solutions
$$
y_+(x) = \lambda_{+}\mathrm{e}^{\sqrt{k}x}
$$
but you also have
$$
y_{-}(x) = \lambda_{-}\mathrm{e}^{-\sqrt{k}x}
$$
and since you have a linear equation as you seen in the other approach
$$
y(x) = y_{+}(x) + y_{-}(x)
$$
is also a solution
$$
y(x) = \lambda_{+}\mathrm{e}^{\sqrt{k}x} + \lambda_{-}\mathrm{e}^{-\sqrt{k}x}
$$
and as the comment by @nasser mentions a constant is a constant so you can absorb into a single constant e.g. $\frac{a}{2} + \frac{b}{2}i = \lambda_{+}$ etc.